# Imap not returning all emails

Tags: php, imap

I'm cycling through my emails using imap and for some reason (possibly a timeout) it reaches about 130 out of the 170 emails and cuts off.

```
function pop3_login($hostz,$portz,$userz,$passz,$folderz,$sslz){
    $sslz=($sslz==false)?"/novalidate-cert":"";
    return (imap_open("{"."$hostz:$portz/pop3$sslz"."}$folderz",$userz,$passz));
}

$msg_int = 1; 

$connection = pop3_login("mail.***","110","me@me.com","***","INBOX",false);
$inbox_msg_count = imap_num_msg($connection);

while($msg_int <= $inbox_msg_count) {
    echo "$msg_int OF $inbox_msg_count <br>";
    $header = imap_header($connection, $msg_int);
    $from = $header->reply_to;
    $subject = $header->subject;

    foreach ($from as $id => $object) {
        $fromname = $object->personal;
        $fromaddress = $object->mailbox . "@" . $object->host;
        $date1 = $header->date;
        $date2 = strtotime($date1);
        $senddate = date("Y-m-d", $date2);
        $emaildatetime = (int)date("U", $date2);    
        echo "Current email Scanned: ". $fromaddress . "<br>";  
    }                   
    $msg_int++;
}
imap_expunge($connection);
imap_close($connection);
```

I was thinking it might be a timeout connection issue because it's actually running fine but just not finishing, so I've set my php.ini timeouts and waits to an absurd amount, along with `imap_timeout(1,999)` and `imap_timeout(2,999)` but it's still cutting off short (and not necessarily in the same exact position, but between 128-132ish of 170).

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: check if the mail server itself has limitations

Comment: Except you're not using IMAP.  You're using POP3.  If you're connecting to Gmail, they window your POP3 messages.

Comment: Why did you add z to the variables of the pop3_login sample code?